# What are the motion planning benchmarks?

Tags: machine-learning-model, model-evaluations, generative-models

Suppose I wanted to try and improve on existing motion planning algorithms. What benchmarks should I be trying to beat?

Papers with code site has no motion planning benchmarks. I searched online and found the [Planner Arena](http://plannerarena.org/)

Is this it or did I miss something? Are there widely recognized benchmarks in the field?